# Python Django query error: Can't convert 'method' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city_icon = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    city_background = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    city_render_separate = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'City: ' + self.get_city_en

    def get_city_en(self):
        searched_city = models.CityLanguage.objects.filter(city_language__exact='EN', city__exact=self)
        if not searched_city:
            return 'Something went wrong...'
        else:
            return searched_city[0].city_name


class CityLanguage(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    city_language = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                     choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                     default=ENGLISH)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Basically its a 2 tables. One for the "City Entity" and another for all of its translations.

Whenever I add a new city using the Django admin interface I get the following error:

**Can't convert 'method' object to str implicitly**

And it refers to the following line of code:

```
return 'City: ' + self.get_city_en
```

I am guessing my mistake is with the query I am trying to run.

My goal:

Because the "City" table doesn't store any strings which help identify the city by a name, I want to return the "English" variant of the city name from the CityLanguage table.

Can someone help me identify what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try `return 'City: ' + self.get_city_en()`

Answer (score 2):

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'City: ' + self.get_city_en()
```

You want the result of the function call. What you're doing is trying to concatenate a function with a string. Consider:

```
def foo():
  return "test"

print foo    # <function foo at 0x1052b0aa0>
print foo()  # "Test"
```

Comment: Thanks Kit! I did miss the  ( ). However: __str__() should be used with Python3 - reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods

Comment: @Aivoric Ohh, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer thanks to @Kit Sunde. Had 2 mistakes. Corrected code below:

```
return 'City: ' + self.get_city_en()


searched_city = CityLanguage.objects.filter(city_language__exact='EN', city__exact=self)
```

I was trying to reference the CityLanguage table by specifying models.CityLanguage which is incorrect. Should just be CityLanguage.